# Building Qt: 'make clean' causes everything to get recompiled?

Tags: linux, compiling, software-installation, make, qt

(This applies to `Qt` versions >= 4.7.3.) I made an attempt to build `Qt` with custom parameters on my Debian box and it actually took AGES to compile (IIRC more than 6 hours on a single-core CPU). That's why I wanted to make sure I won't make any stupid mistakes in the process. However, I chose to do a `make clean` to get the `*.o` files and other stuff cleaned up after successful linking. It seemed a bad idea! For I did a `make install` just after that, and you won't believe it, the `make clean` attempt caused *everything* to get recompiled after the cleanup process! 
Though up to now, I've been thinking that `make clean` does allow a neat installation even with all object files and related stuff removed. Obviously, with `Qt`, things are different.

In the official documentation for `Qt 4.7` (cf. http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.7/install-x11.html), they did not even mention an *optional* `make clean` in the sequence of commands. As I know now, for a good reason.
All the same, I can't call this "complying with standards" as I've already compiled hundreds of open-source apps, and NEVER did `make clean` trigger any recompilation process nor remove anything that should be kept (unless there was a bug in there)

Comment: In any sane system, `make clean` cleans up the build directory. Of course everything would get compiled again. I don't know what you've been working with that `make clean` wouldn't have this effect, but it doesn't sound particularly sane.

Comment: In my case QT 5.2.1 with clean option did not remove old QML files from build directory - they was still used instead of right files which was the same name but different directory

Comment: @fider Hence this question. :) QT5 is not QT4 (note QT5 must have been in a 'post-natal' state when I started this question back in 2012 :)) , so the current behavior when building v5 may differ quite a bit from the v4 behavior one got used to from the 'days of yore'.

Answer (score 7):

I don't know where you got the idea that doing a `make clean` before a `make install` was somehow something you should be doing.

The canonical `INSTALL` file for autotools spells out the process:

1. `./configure`
2. `make`
3. `make check` (optional)
4. `make install`
5. `make installcheck` (optional)

At item 6, it says:

> You can remove the **program binaries** and object files from the source code directory by typing `make clean`.

(Emphasis mine.)

`make clean` is something you do before recompiling, to make sure you get a clean build and don't have left-over by-products from previous runs. You can do it *after* a `make install` if you want to free some space but keep the source and configuration around. You should *not* do it before installing.

Comment: Well, I think my main problem was that I thought what you were trying to explain was "already" a `make distclean`and not `make clean`. I had assumed `make clean` to be a lot less "drastic". :) Obviously I was wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Qt build script works like this:

```
1 First build qmake
2 Generate Makefile for a subprojects (*.pro)
3 Start building libaries, then examples and demo projects
```

Yes, make clean will clean everything but your config file generated by Qt.

My trick is remove the "demo" and "examples" in the top *.pro file, which save about 40% time (on a i5 CPU)

Anway, you could setup ccache to speed up compiling, but that requires about 2G+ disk space for buffering

Comment: Yeah, you're right: that demos/examples stuff is indeed a very huge part of the story. Saved me lots of time indeed. I knew that already, but thanks for pointing it out anyway. :)